# What is the form of a unitary $U$ that preserves the marginals on a given state, $\text{Tr}_A(U\rho_{AB} U^\dagger) = \rho_B$?

Tags: quantum-state, unitarity, linear-algebra

Suppose for some quantum state $\rho_{AB}$ and unitary $U_{AB}$, one has

$$\text{Tr}_A(U\rho U^\dagger) = \rho_B$$

does this imply that $U_{AB} = U_A\otimes I_B$?

Also, the same question as above, but if it holds for all states, $\rho_{AB}$, is that sufficient to claim that $U_{AB} = U_A\otimes I_B$?

Answer (score 2):

There might be a better way to see this, but:

1. If $\rho$ is a pure product state, then yes, this implies that $U$ is also a local unitary operation. To see this, write $\rho=\mathbb P(\psi)\otimes\mathbb P(\phi)$ with $\mathbb P(\psi)\equiv|\psi\rangle\!\langle\psi|$ projector onto $|\psi\rangle$. Then
   $$\operatorname{Tr}_A(U\rho U^\dagger) = \sum_k \mathbb P(A_k |\phi\rangle),$$
   where $A_k\equiv (\langle k|\otimes I)U (|\psi\rangle\otimes I)$. Note that we are essentially just doing the Kraus decomposition of the channel $\mathbb P(\phi)\mapsto \operatorname{Tr}_A[U(\mathbb P(\psi)\otimes\mathbb P(\phi)) U^\dagger]$.

   So, the result of this operation is a convex combination of (rescaled versions of) the projectors $\mathbb P(A_k|\phi\rangle)$. If the result of this operation is to be a single projector $\mathbb P(\phi)$, being this by definition an extremal point, this is only possible if all $A_k|\phi\rangle$ are collinear, which in turn means that the channel has a single nontrivial Kraus operator (*i.e.* its Choi has rank 1).

   More explicitly, that means that there are unitaries $U_1,U_2$ such that $U=U_1\otimes U_2$, where $U_1$ is such that $U_1|\psi\rangle=|k\rangle$, and then in turn we must have $U_2=I$.
2. On the opposite side, consider the totally mixed state, $\rho=I/d_A d_B$ with $d_A,d_B$ the dimensions of the two spaces. Then your condition is clearly satisfied for any $U$, including non-local ones.

Answer (score 2):

As glS says, if you can transform a single pure state $|\psi\rangle$ into another $|\phi\rangle$ with the same marginals, then there always exists a way of performing the transformation using a unitary of the form $U_A\otimes I$. You can easily see this in terms of the Schmidt decomposition of the two states. While this is always possible, it does not mean it is the *only* form that can achieve this. After all,
$$
U|\psi\rangle=|\phi\rangle
$$
only defines one row of the unitary matrix, and there remains much freedom in the way it can be completed. I don't know if that's what the question *meant*, but I read it as asking to enumerate all those possibilities. Practically, that's not a very interesting thing to do.

On the other hand, if you demand a $U$ for which *any* bipartite pure state's marginals will be preserved, then, yes, $U_A\otimes I$ is the only way of writing this. We start to prove this by noting that $U$ must not be entangling: by definition, an entangling gate takes some separable state and makes it entangled, and hence there must be at least one state for which the marginals are not preserved. Thus, $U$ must be of separable form, meaning it's either$^1$
$$
U_A\otimes U_B\qquad \text{or}\qquad (U_A\otimes U_B)\cdot\text{SWAP}.
$$
In this first case, it's trivial that $U_B=I$, which we can verify simply by examining the action of $U$ on separable basis states. In the second case, a similar examination would require
$$
U_B=V_BV_A^\dagger
$$
where $V_A$ and $V_B$ are the unitaries that convert some basis into the Schmidt bases of the two systems. This is clearly state dependent and therefore cannot work in general.

$^1$ I'm confident this is true for two qubits. I believe it's true for higher dimensional systems, but there's always a risk that my memory is being coloured by working with qubits too much.